# code not running after publishing on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Actually i want to run  class file dynamically without restarting server
and i tried with the following code.

the below code works fine on localhost, but it does not works when published  on server

```
CompilerParameters CompilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
string outputDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

CompilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
CompilerParams.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
CompilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
CompilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/optimize";

string[] references = { "System.dll", "System.Linq.dll", AppSession.Analytics.ServerMapPath + "/BITool.dll", "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll", AppSession.Analytics.ServerMapPath + "/RDotNet.dll", AppSession.Analytics.ServerMapPath + "/DynamicInterop.dll", "System.Core.dll", AppSession.Analytics.ServerMapPath + "/System.Dynamic.dll" };
CompilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(references);

CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerResults compile = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParams, code);

if (compile.Errors.HasErrors)
{
    string text = "Compile error: ";
    foreach (CompilerError ce in compile.Errors)
    {
        text += "rn" + ce.ToString();
    }
    throw new Exception(text);
}

//ExpoloreAssembly(compile.CompiledAssembly);
Module module = compile.CompiledAssembly.GetModules()[0];
Type mt = null;
MethodInfo methInfo = null;

if (module != null)
{
    mt = module.GetType("BITool.Concrete.RIntegration");
}

if (mt != null)
{
    methInfo = mt.GetMethod("RConnectFn");
}

if (methInfo != null)
{
    methInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
}
```

Can anyone suggest me a method  to achieve this??

Comment: @Schuere u have mistake i just need to run   class file dynamically without restarting server

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Didn't see the part without resetting, Deleted Comment

Comment: Actually i am not getting any error, only the functionality is not working properly

Comment: You cannot run only a class file on the server directly. It works on localhost since if is being compiled locally by .Net CLR. What you need to do is build the project, copy the dll file generated under bin folder (look closely for the specific file to avoid copying all) then replace the dll file on server